# How to set conditions based on Eval() value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have this code

```
<div class="result correct"><%# Eval("QandAID") %></div>
```

and I am wondering how I can set conditions on the value, I.e if the eval value is 2 change div class to "result incorrect" else leave as "result correct". That's also part of the question if anyone knows how to do that (change the div class based on the condition), then that would be a bonus.

Oh and I have that code inside a repeater bound to a dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a property in the Page class:

```
public int MyValue { get; set; }
```

Then access it in the page this way:

```
<div style='width: <%=MyValue %>px'></div>
```

This example should answer indirectly your question and open up some more possibilities on how to put values into HTML that may or may not be bound to a DataRow.

Another example:

```
<%# Eval("QandAid") == 2 ? "result incorrect" : "result correct" %>
```

Or:

```
<div class='<%# Eval("QandAid") == 2 ? "class1" : "class2" %>'>
```

Comment: Both answers work, yours brings up another question though, what is the difference between <%=  and <%# ?

Comment: <%= is C# embedded script with access to the code behind, whereas <%# is bound to the DataRow undergoing the rendering, instead of the Page.

Comment: I just ran your last line of code and it keeps throwing an error...Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

Comment: Eval("QandAid") returns an object. You can try to unbox it with an (int) cast or QandAid is of another type you can cast to. Eval just returns an object that has to be cast to make something useful, like this: ((MyClass)Eval("myVar")).X == 2 or similar

Comment: As you were commenting I had changed it to convert.int32(Eval("QandAID")) == 1 and it worked. After awhile i clicked in and realized I had to convert it or cast it.

Answer (score 1):

This should happen outside of the markup. Make the class a property of your model and set it based on your condition:

```
class YourModel {
    public int QandAID { get; set; }
    public string ValidityClass {
        get {
            return QandAID == 1 ? "correct" : "incorrect";
        }
    }
}
```

Then your repeater template becomes something like this:

```
<div class='result <%# Eval("ValidityClass") %>'><%# Eval("QandAID") %></div>
```

Comment: As above with the other answer, it works. Yours brings up a question as well. Why are we able to access public strings, but not a method in the codebehind?

Comment: Because `Eval` uses reflection to find fields or properties on the object being data bound. It does not look for methods.

Comment: ok, that explains why I could never call a method that way. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I just ran this and it throws this error ...DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ValidityClass'.

Comment: You should use <%=ValidityClass %> because it is a property in the code behind context, not a propterty of the DataRow.

Comment: @pid, an hour or so ago you explained the difference between the = and #, and here is where I should have remembered what you explained